# Angular 6 firebase snapshot returns undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular6

I am uploading object to my database and then trying to retrieve all items. On the second step I get errors. :

**My object class :**

```
export class Data {
  $key: string;
  name: string;
  address: string;
  address2: string;
  pscode: string;
  ccode: string;
  name2: string;
  trucks: Trucks;
  trailers: Trailers;
  email: string;
  phone: string;
  city: string;
  country: string;
}
```

**My service upload object (works fine) :**

```
busines = {} as Data;


createItemAuth() {
   this.afDatabase.list(`users/${this.auth.userId}/company/`).push(this.busines)
}
```

**My service getUpload :**

```
 getItem: Observable<any[]>;
 getUploads() {
    this.getItem = this.afDatabase.list(`users/${this.auth.userId}/company/`).snapshotChanges().pipe(map(items => {
      return items.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.val();
        const $key = a.payload.key;
        const $ref = a.payload.ref;
        return { $key, ...data, $ref };
      });
    }));
    return this.getItem;
  }
```

**Calling it in component :**

```
uploads: Observable<Data[]>;
ngOnInit() {
   this.uploads = this.back.getUploads();
   console.log(this.back.getUploads())
}
```

**HTML: (nothing at all at browser)**

```
<div *ngFor="let info of uploads | async">
  <p>{{info.name}}</p>
</div>
```

**Console.log on ngOnInit() :**

> Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator:
>   MapOperator} operator: MapOperator {project: ƒ, thisArg: undefined}
>   source: Observable {_isScalar: false, _subscribe: ƒ}
>   _isScalar: false
>   **proto**: Object

Versioning :

```
"rxjs": "^6.1.0",
  "firebase": "^5.4.1",
  "@angular/cli": "6.0.0",
    "typescript": "2.7.2",
```

Comment: what does `{{info}}` displaying?

Comment: nothing at all, tried without async - differ Object in Object

Comment: Try `this.back.getUploads().subribe((item: any) => {})` an observable have to be subribed. Guess it's a long day and you need some rest ;)

Comment: now I get undefined in console.

Comment: You `console.log(item)` within the subscription?

Comment: probably mapping inside the `getUploads` functions returns null

Comment: I think yes, returns null, but the path are the same so why null, I dont know

Comment: Changes map operation and it worked !

Answer (score 2):

I had to change the following code :

**From this :**

```
  getUploads() {
    this.getItem = this.afDatabase.list(`users/${this.auth.userId}/company/`).snapshotChanges().pipe(map(items => {
      return items.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.val();
        const $key = a.payload.key;
        const $ref = a.payload.ref;
        return { $key, ...data, $ref };
      });
    }));
    return this.getItem;
  }
```

**To this :**

```
 getUploads() {
    this.getItem = this.afDatabase.list(`users/${this.auth.userId}/company/`).snapshotChanges().map((actions) => {
      return actions.map((a) => {
        const data = a.payload.val();
        const $key = a.payload.key;
        const $ref = a.payload.ref;
        return { $key, ...data, $ref };
      });
    });
    return this.getItem;
  }
```