# angular firebase Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Date

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I get the error.

> cannot read property 'toDate' of undefined. Without the `toDate() | Date`

i get

> Timestamp(seconds=1545109200, nanoseconds=0)

I referenced this [Angular 6 firebase snapshot returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52536786/angular-6-firebase-snapshot-returns-undefined)

however its not specific to get converting a timestampe to a readable date string. 
the desired output would be Dec 6, 2018. Along those lines.

**schedule-list.component.html**

```
<div class="container ">
    <div class="row">
      <div *ngFor="let appoint of list" class="col-md-8 myCenter mt-2"> 
        <!-- the bottom code should work if items within list exist. -->
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
              Title: {{appoint.name}}

          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <p>{{appoint.appointment_date.toDate() | date}}</p>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**schedule.model.ts**

```
export class Schedule {
    name:string;
    appointment_date:string;
}
```

**Pipe.ts**

```
import {formatDate} from '@angular/common';
import {Inject, LOCALE_ID, Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
import {firestore} from 'firebase/app';
import Timestamp = firestore.Timestamp;

@Pipe({
  name: 'fireStoreDatePipe'
})
export class FireStoreDatePipePipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) private locale: string) {
  }

  transform(timestamp: Timestamp, format?: string): string {
      return formatDate(timestamp.toDate(), format || 'medium', this.locale);
  }
}
```

**Schedule-list.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { ScheduleService } from '../schedule.service';
import { Schedule } from '../models/schedule.model';
import {FireStoreDatePipePipe} from '../fire-store-date-pipe.pipe';
import { Timestamp } from '@firebase/firestore-types';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-schedule-list',
  templateUrl: './schedule-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./schedule-list.component.css']
})
export class ScheduleListComponent implements OnInit {
  list:Schedule[];
  constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore, private service: ScheduleService ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getAppointments().subscribe(actionArray =>{
      this.list = actionArray.map(item =>{
        return{
          ...item.payload.doc.data()
        } as Schedule;
      })
    });
  }

  getSchedules(){
    return this.firestore.collection('schedules').snapshotChanges();
  }

}
```

Comment: what happen without the pipe. `{{appoint.appointment_date.toDate() }}`

Comment: its already explained in the post above the code.

Comment: just the pipe. keep the `toDate()`

Comment: thats not what i want. I need to get the date that client picked on datepicker. So i would need to get the appointment_date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to multiply your timestamp by 1000, I've already faced the same problem;

try this:

```
<p>{{ appoint.appointment_date.seconds * 1000 | date:'dd:MM:yyyy hh:mm:ss' }}</p>
```

Comment: Can I ask you how seconds * 1000 give you the date I'm a little confused here?

Comment: this is didnt work. `Cannot read property 'seconds' of undefined`

Comment: Sure @Swoox, JavaScript works with milliseconds, so you have to transform your timestamp from seconds to milliseconds multiplying by 1000;

Comment: @BARNOWL Can you check if you are getting the data properly?

Comment: 1 second * 1000 = 1000 seconds hmm? To make a milisecond you do 1 / 1000 right?

Comment: 1 second = 1000 milliseconds xD

Comment: Ahh so you imply the seconds is just a number so you make it one milisecond and multiply 1000 smart :) I will try this in my own code aswell ty.

Comment: @BARNOWL pro tip: `{{ appoint | json }}`; The json pipe may be useful in your case, to check the object properties.

Comment: thanks for the pro tip I got this `{ "appointmentdate": { "seconds": 1545282000, "nanoseconds": 0 }, "name": "John Wayne" }`

Comment: So there it is, the correct property name is `appointmentdate` not `appointment_date`. Hope it helped you.

Comment: but i still get `Timestamp(seconds=1545282000, nanoseconds=0)`

Comment: i think i got it `Thu Dec 20 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)`

Comment: i did this `appoint.appointmentdate.toDate()` thank you for your help man, i just gotta figure out the date structure

Answer (score 0):

Cause you have a timestamp with the second you can do the following to make it a date:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getAppointments().subscribe(actionArray =>{
      this.list = actionArray.map(item =>{
        return{
          ...item.payload.doc.data()
        } as Schedule;
      })
      for(let i = 0; i < this.list.length; i++){
        console.log(this.list[i].appointment_date); // to see if the data is undefined!
        this.list[i].appointment_date = new Date(new Date(0).setUTCSeconds(this.list[i].appointment_date.seconds));
      }
    });
  }
));
```

Comment: where would  i insert this ?

Comment: Somewhere in the subsctribe after you set the items.

Comment: I see, so would i still reference it like this `{{appoint.appointment_date.toDate() | date}}`

Comment: So i wouldn't need to refer to it like that or no ? im sorry im just a little bit unfamiliar with angular.

Comment: Well you just translate the seconds to a date and replace the current value. In the template it can be done like `{{appoint.appointment_date | date:'dd:MM:yyyy'}}`

Comment: Also try to test if `this.list[i].appointment_date` exist. Cause you say in the other answer it's undefined.

Comment: Im having troubles on where to insert the code u had as an answer, would it be possible u can edit it to match it with code in the thread.

Comment: sorry for the delay, i get `Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'string'` on `this.list[i].appointment_date` it could be `appointment_date:string` im going to switch it to any

Comment: even when switching the model from string to any it render nothing for the appointment_date field.

Comment: i get this error `ScheduleListComponent.html:6 ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert "Timestamp(seconds=1545109200, nanoseconds=0)" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'`

Comment: You should really use `console.log()` to see the values in your console of the browser. I can't help you any futher cause I have no clue how your `this.list` look like.